# What is this yellow "fat" thing on my bacon

Tags: meat, bacon, spoilage, fat

[image: Bacon]

Searching in google for yellow bacon fat returns nothing

I'm assuming it's fat, but have never seen a large yellow lump of it on any bacon I have had in the past.

Would this still be good to eat? (Already ate half the pack...)

Answer (score 2):

That's a piece of the rind of the bacon, which is yellow because it was exposed to the smoke. The bacon shifted while being sliced, causing the strip to end up attached to that one piece rather than in bits on the others. It's fine to eat.

Comment: Is it not a bit thick for the rind or has it been flattened? Also isn't the rind normally more solid compared to fat? I used to get rind bacon, but it was always a really thin solidish piece on the end

Comment: No, that looks like normal thickness. It's not just the skin, it's the area exposed to the smoke.

Comment: @123 - It's not 'thick' per se. It's turned 90°. That piece would have started out as the equivalent of 5 or 6 slices, but as it was cut, the machine has not quite gone through it until that slice. It should really have been attached to most of the rest of the pack, as a tiny bit on the corner of each slice. In fact the next slice up may have been 'properly' cut - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sdzdi.png

Answer (score -1):

The slab of bacon where these slices came from, seems to have been slightly irregular shaped at that corner, so that when was cut, it didn’t give the uniform slices the customer is used to. This particular part was cut so that the layer of fat and skin/rind was cut on the bias, making the layers appear wider than when cut perpendicularly.

[image: detail]

I suspect that the processing machinery “saw” slices within the expected width and so they ended up in the package. Irregularly shaped parts of the meat are often sold separately, e.g. as small cubes or otherwise cut up more.

In short, your bacon is perfectly fine.